# Retrieving data from a Python Tuple

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to retrieve and reuse data from a JSON object in a for loop in Python. An example of a single JSON object below:

```
{
    "id": "123456789",
    "envs": [
        "env:remote1",
        "env:remote2",
        "env:remote3"
    ],
    "moves": {
        "sequence1": "half glass full",
        "sequence2": "half glass empty"
    }
}
```

For loop example

```
for i in ids:
    print(i["envs"])
    print(i["moves"])
```

`envs` will be successfully printed since it is a list. However, since `moves` is a tuple I receive a KeyError as it is looking for a key in a dictionary. What is the Python recommended way of pulling data from a tuple in this instance. For example, I want to print `sequence1` or `sequence2`.

Thanks

Comment: The value associated with the *moves* key is a dictionary - not a tuple. Also, in order to clarify your issue, please show the code where *ids* is assigned

Comment: JSON doesn't even support the *concept* of a tuple.  What is the actual error message you're receiving?  (Possibly one of your JSON objects lacks the `"moves"` key.)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you made a typographic error.

From this code

```
ids = [
    {
        "id": "123456789",
        "envs": [
            "env:remote1",
            "env:remote2",
            "env:remote3",
        ],
        "moves": {
            "sequence1": "half glass full",
            "sequence2": "half glass empty",
        },
    }
]
for i in ids:
    print(i["envs"])
    print(i["moves"])
```

I obtain these results

```
['env:remote1', 'env:remote2', 'env:remote3']
{'sequence1': 'half glass full', 'sequence2': 'half glass empty'}
```